# Idiomatic clojure for ith and i+1th element looping

Tags: recursion, for-loop, clojure, lisp

I have been trying to think how to implement an [algorithm](http://www.engr.colostate.edu/~dga/dga/papers/point_in_polygon.pdf) to compute the winding number of a polygon with respect to a point.  Currently the implementation is as follows: (note updated so code works)

```
(defn winding-num
  "Return winding number of polygon
  see Alciatore "
  [poly point]
        ; translate poly such that point is at origin
  (let [translated-poly (map #(vec-f - % point) poly)]
    ; w is wind-num
    (loop [vertices translated-poly w 0]
      (cond
        (= (count vertices) 1)
        w

        :else
        (let [x1 (first (first vertices))
              x2 (first (second vertices))
              y1 (second (first vertices))
              y2 (second (second vertices))]
          (cond 
            (and (< (* y1 y2) 0)
                 (> (+ x1 (/ (* y1 (- x2 x1))
                         (- y1 y2)))
                    0))
            (if (< y1 0)
                (recur (rest vertices) (inc w))
                (recur (rest vertices) (dec w)))

            (and (zero? y1)
                 (> x1 0))
            (if (> y2 0)
                (recur (rest vertices) (+ w 0.5))
                (recur (rest vertices) (- w 0.5)))

            (and (zero? y2)
                 (> x2 0))
            (if (< y1 0)
                 (recur (rest vertices) (+ w 0.5))
                 (recur (rest vertices) (- w 0.5)))

            :else
            (recur (rest vertices) w)))))))
```

My problems with this are

- People say it's preferable when possible to use looping constructs which operate at a higher level than explicit recursion; for instance `map`, `for`, `reduce`, etc.
- The rest function converts the vector into a list

I could think of an implementation using `for` and indices, but I also hear it is preferable to not use indices.

Is there an idiomatic way for dealing with vector algorithms which in each iteration need access to consecutive values?

Comment: vec-f is just a function I wrote to make doing vector operations more convenient, in this case it it minuses one vector from another

Comment: As Rob said below, you're probably looking for partition. If you're going for speed though, using loop/recur is supposed to be fastest. You might also want to consider using destructuring in the let to remove some duplication like this:
(let [[[x1 y1] [x2 y2]] verticies
      coll (rest vertices)] ...

Answer (score 4):

In general if you want to access consecutive values of a sequence, two at a time, you can use the partition function.  Partition allows you to specify a group size as well as a step size:

```
user> (partition 2 1 (range 10))
((0 1) (1 2) (2 3) (3 4) (4 5) (5 6) (6 7) (7 8) (8 9))
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the shape of your algorithm. Generally speaking higher-level constructs are more understandable than explicit recursion, but sometimes the shape of the problem makes this less clear.

Other things to note:

`rest` returns a sequence, not a list. This shouldn't matter here.

You should make use of destructuring.  For example:

```
    (let [x1 (first (first vertices))
          x2 (first (second vertices))
          y1 (second (first vertices))
          y2 (second (second vertices))
```

This can be replaced by:

```
(let [[x1 y1] [x2 y2]] vertices] ... )
```

However this is not a very difficult algorithm to implement with `reduce`:

```
(defn inc-dec 
  "Convenience function for incrementing and decrementing"
  ([condition i] (if condition (inc i) (dec i)))
  ([condition i amount] (if condition (+ i amount) (- i amount))))

(defn winding-num
  [poly point]
  (let [translated-poly (map #(map - % point) poly)
        winding-reducer
          (fn winding-reducer [w [[x1 y1] [x2 y2]]]
            (cond 
              (and (< (* y1 y2) 0)
                      ; r
                   (> (+ x1 (/ (* y1 (- x2 x1))
                           (- y1 y2)))
                      0))
               (inc-dec (< y1 0) w)

              (and (zero? y1) (> x1 0))
               (inc-dec (> y2 0) w 0.5)

              (and (zero? y2) (> x2 0))
               (inc-dec (< y1 0) w 0.5)

              :else w))
        ]
    (reduce winding-reducer 0 (partition 2 1 translated-poly))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the destructuring, I knew this but haven't got around to learning the syntax.  How does one get around the 'rest'?  I'll update the code now to a working and complete one, a simple test case would be (winding-num [[0.0 0.0] [1.0 0.0] [1.0 1.0] [0.0 1.0]] [0.5 0.5]) This is a box with the polygon in the middle and the winding number should be 0.  If you move the point outside, i.e. second argument is [2.0 2.0], it should evaluate to 1.

Comment: I think you have those results backwards?

Comment: This post is a great intro to destructuring: http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code is using `(map func seq (rest seq))` to handle the pair of points used by the algorithm.  It also fixes two problems with the original implementation:

It works whether or not the polygon is specified by repeating the first point as the last, i.e. giving the same result for both

```
[[1 1][-1 1][-1 -1][1 -1]] and 

[[1 1][-1 1][-1 -1][1 -1][1 1]]
```

It also works for polygons that have successive points on the positive    x-axis, whereas the original (*and the refered pseudo code*) will    substract `1/2`for each line segment along the x-axis.

```
(defn translate [vec point]
   (map (fn [p] (map - p point)) vec))

(defn sign [x]
  (cond (or (not (number? x)) (zero? x)) 0
        (pos? x) 1
        :else -1))

(defn winding-number [polygon point]
  (let [polygon (translate (conj polygon (first polygon)) point)]
     (reduce +
          (map (fn [[x1 y1][x2 y2]]
                   (cond (and (neg? (* y1 y2))
                              (pos? (- x2 (* y2 (/ (- x2 x1) (- y2 y1))))))
                           (sign y2)
                         (and (zero? y1) (pos? x1))
                           (sign y2)
                         (and (zero? y2) (pos? x2))
                           (sign y1)
                         :else 0))
                polygon (rest polygon)))))
```